# Hibernate SQL QUERY, problem with TEXT data type in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I need to perform a sql query with hibernate ( no mapping ) but i keep getting this error whenever a field has a TEXT data type in MYSQL :

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1
```

I don't know what to do, mapping is not an option ( dynamic tables in the database , so the number of fields is variable ).

Here's the piece of code :

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);

Object[] values = (Object[]) query.uniqueResult();
```

sql is a String containing the query ( it runs ok with mysql query engine ). If I change the TEXT data type to varchar, works fine, but that's not an option neither !

Any clues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```
package iam.dirty;
import java.sql.Types;

import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
import org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect;

public class DialectForGkoloc extends SQLServerDialect {
     public DialectForGkoloc() {
        super();

        registerHibernateType(Types.DECIMAL, Hibernate.BIG_DECIMAL.getName());   
        registerHibernateType(-1, Hibernate.STRING.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.LONGVARCHAR, Hibernate.TEXT.getName());
     }

}
```

Modify the Hibernate configuration file hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="dialect"> 
 org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect 
</property>
```

with:

```
<property name="dialect"> 
 iam.dirty.DialectForGkoloc 
</property>
```

Comment: It worked ! The only change i had to do was to remove the Hibernate.xxxxx.getName(), and add a simple string.

For example : 
`registerHibernateType(Types.LONGVARCHAR, "text");`

Answer (score 0):

A quick google (you did try this first, right?) suggest addScalar is your friend here.

Comment: Yes, of course, i tried google AND addScalar. The problem is that the field name is also variable.

The table name is variable, the field names are variable and the number of fields is also variable. 

Assume something like : 

table_x with field_1, field_2, field_3.
table_y with field_1, field_2
table_z with field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4, field_5