# Getting dynamically generated column names from result of Hibernate native query

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, hibernate

I'm executing stored procedure with Hibernate native method, this stored procedure creates column names depending on another table Ids. So its columns look like something like this:

> | id | ... some other columns ... | name | c_1 | c_2 | c_4 | c_.. |

If I call `Query.getResultList()`  it returns `List<Object[]>`, and I don't know column names. I have to know column names (and corresponding column index) to continue my further business logic. I also cannot use `EntityManager.createNativeQuery(String s, Class aClass)` since it is not one POJO class.

Currently I'm getting `List<Object[]>` without problem, but I need, for example, `Map<String,Object[]>`  column name as a key and column values as an array of Objects.

How can I get all column names with their values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, found the solution, and I'm going to share with you(maybe helps someone). Here is what I did:

- I added Spring JDBC Support to my application, then,
- I used Spring SimpleJdbcTemplate Querying, there is a method:   [`SimpleJdbcDaoSupport.getSimpleJdbcTemplate().queryForList(nativeQuery)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcTemplate.html#queryForList%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) which returns `List<Map<String,Object>>`

Answer (score 0):

(This is just an idea, I haven't tested it. And it needs Criteria API.)

If you manage to get the result as `List<javax.persistence.Tuple>`, you can take one `Tuple` and call `getElements()` on it - you'll get a list of `TupleElement<?>`s on which you can call `getAlias()`. Presumably this will be the column name. But I'm not 100% sure and it won't work if there are no tuples (results) returned, but I think it's worth a try. See [9.2. Tuple criteria queries](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-tuple).

For this approach, this might help:

- [Calling stored procedure from Java / JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572626/calling-stored-procedure-from-java-jpa)
- [How can i call stored procedure using spring with jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886401/how-can-i-call-stored-procedure-using-spring-with-jpa)