# How to call PLSQL (Oracle) package in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, oracle, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, plsql

I can execute normal queries via javax.persistence.EntityManager.

I really have no idea as of the moment. I'll try to search further after this post and if you guys could shed some light, I'd really appreciate it.

Thank you :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886401/how-can-i-call-stored-procedure-using-spring-with-jpa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `javax.persistence.EntityManager`,

get a raw connection using

```
private Connection getConnection(final EntityManager em) {
      HibernateEntityManager hem = (HibernateEntityManager) em;
      SessionImplementor sim = (SessionImplementor) hem.getSession();
      return sim.connection();
}
```

then do something like

```
public boolean myProc(EntityManager pentityManager, String param1, BigDecimal param2, String param3) throws SQLException {

        boolean result = false;

        Connection conn = getConnection(pentityManager); /* code above */
        CallableStatement cs;

        cs = conn.prepareCall("{CALL myPackage.myProc( ?, ?, ?, ? )}");

        //IN params
        cs.setString(1, param1);
        cs.setBigDecimal(2, param2);
        cs.setString(3, param3);

        //OUT param
        cs.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.BOOLEAN);

        cs.executeUpdate();

        result = cs.getBoolean(4); //get OUT PARAM

        return result;
    }
```