# How to implement the simplest alien in a REST webservice?

Tags: rest, stored-procedures, spring-boot

I need a JSON *endpoint* that return data directally from a [stored procedure](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.stored-procedures). Example:

```java
@Procedure("complex")
String complexStoredProcedure();
```

The simplest case is the GET endpoint with  no parameter...  The returned data is a ([blabck-box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box)) JSON, with no relationship with a Spring *entity*, and no special data-type (an "alien datatype" for my Spring application)...

If you need an example, suppose a simple controller as

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/howto", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@Procedure(name = "MyRandom.random")  // ?? not work
public String howto() { 
    double x = random();  // from stored-procedure call, how to do it?
    return "{\"result\":"+x+"}";
}
```

How to implement it? that is,  **the simplest way to implement a controller method that do it (a call to a stored-procedure)?**

---

EDIT: cleaned the redundant code fragments, transfered to [answer-Wiki below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41895512/287948).

Comment: Can you wire in an entity manager and run a [native query](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7886447)?

Comment: @approxiblue it is not ideal (using Hibernate with JPA 2.1 spec), but yes, I can use some native PostgreSQL 9.6 if there are no good option today.

Comment: For more context, see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/41880120/287948

Answer (score 4):

Im not really sure if I understand your question well but this is my solution.

I created a simple procedure on a `oracle` DB:

```
PROCEDURE TESTPROCOUTPUT
   (param2 OUT VARCHAR2)
   IS
   GETPARAM VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    param2 := 'procedure Called';
END TESTPROCOUTPUT;
```

To use `@Procedure` in the Spring environment you will need an `Entity` and a `Repository`. So I created a simple `Entity` and it's `Repository`:

```
@Entity
public class City {

    @Id
    private String cityCode;

    //...getter/setter
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface LandRepository extends CrudRepository<City, String> {

    @Procedure(name="TESTPROCOUTPUT", outputParameterName="param2")
    String TESTPROCOUTPUT();
}
```

It is important that the method name has the same name like the procedure has. (Not sure if its just for oracle the case. And could also be in camelCase I think)

So in your controller you can now easily autowire the repository (or if you have an implementation of the interface use this).

```
@Controller
public class CityController {

    private CityRepository cityRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value="/howto", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody
    public String howto() { 
        String s = cityRepository.TESTPROCOUTPUT();
        return "{\"result\":" + s + "}";
    }

    public CityRepository getCityRepository () {
        return cityRepository;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setCityRepository (CityRepository cityRepository) {
        this.cityRepository= cityRepository;
    }
}
```

And the result is:

[image]

So you are not able to use `@Procedure` annotation on non repository methods.

> Annotation to declare JPA 2.1 stored procedure mappings directly on repository methods.

Comment: I show in the Wiki-answer a real case full files  (with all non-focus methodos, imports, etc.) to show what I see "simple" in code addiction... But here you can illustrate with cleaner (focus) code... Well, the use of *@Autowired setCityRepository* was good (!), to reduce demand for a *service* file, but how to use it? **there are a good link for general  *@Autowired setXxRepository*?** I try to reproduce syntax at my project but not compile, "cannot find symbol" error.  PS: when I use *service* file all works fine.

Comment: @PeterKrauss can you show your service file? Is it used for constructing the application context of Spring? And what do you else need as an answer to answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

I am trying to respond... It is only "the simplest" for my view point and my basic  tests, you can show another solution to get the bounty.

Starting as " https://stackoverflow.com/q/41880120/287948 " context.... And, as I am using PostgreSQL (where a `SELECT f(x)` is valid), the `@Query` (with  `nativeQuery = true` ) is a workaround for `@Procedure`...

PROBLEMS WITH THIS ANSWER: not used `@Procedure`... After Patrick's answer I see (and edited this line) that you can replace `@Query` to `@Procedure` (and other things as specified by Patrick) that the method is the same!

---

### 3 steps for add "alien `@Query`" in an existent *domain*

Any Spring *domain* can use any `@Query`, so the domain choice is only a kind of "house organization" and semantic, no constraint over your native SQL code and `domain/repository` choice.

1. At domain's `domain.repository` package file, add a method with `@Query` and with other *imports* add all Query-context imports (QueryAnnotation, JpaRepository, query.Param, etc. if need);
2. At domain's `service` package file, add the new custom "find" method definition.
3. At controll's method, call the method defined in the service.

---

### Illustrating with real files

**Step1**: add the new `@Query` into a existing repository file, eg. `myprj/address/domain/repository/ICityRepository.java`

```java
package com.myprj.address.domain.repository;  // old

import com.myprj.address.domain.entity.City;   //old
// ... other project's specific (old)
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository; 
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query; // new
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param; // new
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.Procedure; // new

@Repository
public interface ICityRepository extends BaseRepository<City, Long> { //old
    Page<City> findByState(State state, Pageable pageable); //old

    // here an alien example! (simplest is a call to a constant value)
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value= "SELECT 1234.5678") // NEW! 
    Double findCustom();

}
```

The *alien* is there!

**Step2**: import repository and  add defined `findCustom()` into a existing service file, eg. `myprj/address/service/CityService.java`

```java
package com.myprj.address.service; // old

import com.myprj.address.domain.entity.City;
// ... other project's specific (old)

@Service   
public class CityService 
       extends BaseService<City, ICityRepository, Long> {   // old

    @Autowired
    public CityService(ICityRepository repository) {super(repository);} // old

    public Page<City> findByState(State state, Pageable pageable) {
        return repository.findByState(state, pageable);
    } // old

    public Double findCustom() { return repository.findCustom(); }  // NEW!!

}
```

**Step3**: add defined `cityService.findCustom()` into a existing controller file, eg. `myprj/address/controller/CityController.java`   ... It is a dummy *endpoint* to test and show the query result,

```java
package com.myprj.address.controller;  // old

import com.myprj.address.service.CityService;  // reuse old
// ... other project's specific (old)

@RestController   // old
@RequestMapping(value = "/zip", produces = "application/json")  // old
public class ZipController {   // old

    @Autowired  // old
    private CityService cityService;  // old, so reuse it

    // .. many many endpoints ... OLD    

    // NEW!!
    @RequestMapping(value="/dummy", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public String dummy() {
        double x = cityService.findCustom();
        return "{\"success\":"+x+"}";
    }
}
```

### Reducing to 2 steps and 2 files

As showed by Patrick you can add `@Autowired` to the repository to set it, and use `repository.findCustom()` directly in the `Controller.java` file.