# Call database function with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I need to query a function of the database, by SQL, something so simple  as

`@Query("SELECT random()")`

how to implement a *domain/repository* or *service* method that do it?

Comment: An open question related to this, http://stackoverflow.com/q/41880120/287948

Comment: .. And get a bounty [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41837546/287948)!

Answer (score 5):

There are [various ways how to bind stored procedures with Spring Data JPA](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.stored-procedures) (using JPA 2.1).

Simplest example:

```
@Procedure("random")
Integer randomStoredProcedure();
```

Comment: Thanks to the docs.spring link and explain that "function" is "stored procedure" in the JPA jargon!   Now a problem to implement it: it is possible to call at a controller? On my code `@Procedure` is "cannot resolve symbol 'Procedure'"

Comment: Correction, it is not integer, is double... So something like `@Procedure("random")
        double x = randomStoredProcedure();`

Comment: ...  But need to declare more things... where I most declare it? (at *controller*?, at *domain/repository*?)    Examples of other thing to declare:  `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "Double.random", procedureName = "random")` ... but where declare it?

Comment: what should be type of randomStoredProcedure () if db function is 'returns table' function ?

Answer (score 1):

In case, you don't have any Entity/DTO (non @Entity) objects and wondering how to map returned table from the function into your custom object.

```
@Repository
public class YourRepository {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public List<YourObject> findObjects() {
        List<Object[]> columns = entityManager
                .createStoredProcedureQuery("your_sql_func")
                .getResultList();
        return columns.stream().map(this::toYourObject).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private YourObject toYourObject(Object[] columns) {
        return new YourObject((int)columns[0], (String)columns[1]);
    }

}

class YourObject {

    private int number;
    private String name;
    
    public YourObject(int number, String name) {
       this.number = number;
       this.name = name;
    }
    // getters/setters or use Lombok
}
```

If you have any parameters in your function then your query should look like this,

```
List<Object[]> columns = entityManager
     .createStoredProcedureQuery("your_sql_func")
     .registerStoredProcedureParameter("param1Name", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
     .setParameter("param1Name", param1Value)
     .getResultList();
```

You could use native query as well,

```
List<Object[]> columns = entityManager
      .createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM your_sql_func(:param1Name)")
      .setParameter("param1Name", param1Value)
      .getResultList();
```