# Call SQL Server Stored Procedure With a Return Value From Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I need to call a SQL Server Stored Procedure that returns a boolean value, not by output parameter, like this:

```
exec ? = sp_adm_verificapermissao ?,?,?,?
```

I am using Spring Data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i call stored procedure using spring with jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886401/how-can-i-call-stored-procedure-using-spring-with-jpa)

Comment: This question differs because there is a return value in the procedure, that is my problem to get it.

Comment: The accepted answer returns a List from the query result. There is another method that returns an Object. How is that different?